# Exportación de XPZ desde Evo3 a Genexus 15

Tags: genexus

Estoy haciendo una Export All de una KB en Genexus Evo3. Al intentar importarla en Genexus 15, queda la pantalla en blanco, o sea, no carga objetos en la lista. Solo menciona el texto "The export file was converted to new version".

¿ Existe algún inconveniente en la exportación desde GxEvo3 ?

Answer (score 1):

No hay ningún inconveniente en lo que quieres hacer @dmonza, es oficialmente soportado (no al revés).

Por favor comunícate con soporte para poder recabar mas información sobre tu caso.

Comment: ¿Existe algún incidente sobre esto o si hay algo en lo que se haya trabajado para el Gx15 U1?

Answer (score 0):

Tengo entendido que lo recomendado es abrir la KB Evo3 directamente en Genexus 15. No hacer un import del XPZ.
Para esto te convendría respaldar la KB a algún otro lado primero.

Comment: Igual mi idea es seguir manteniendo la KB en Evo3 también. Si hago eso, tengo que tener en cuenta varios otros temas como el nombre de la KB-DB entre otros.